# Аналог/перевод шутки "that's what she said"

Tags: перевод

Есть ли в русском языке какой-то аналог шутки "that's what she said?" Если нет, то как правильно это можно перевести?

Вот страница на [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=that%27s%20what%20she%20said) и [примеры](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIWrFNDKQ6o) использования данной шутки в контексте.

В одном из переводов сериала [The Office](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Office_(U.S._TV_series)) эту фразу перевели как "слова моей подружки". Не уверен, что такой вариант можно назвать лучшим.

Comment: Аналога нет. Переводить можно, но получится тупо. Оно и в оригинале не блещет, но там все привыкли.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have just found this expression (that's what she said) on the Internet translated as "гусары, молчать". It is also used when somebody can only think of sexual connotation of a sentence or an expression. It comes from a well-known joke: http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=76781

There's also a popular expression "каждый понимает в меру своей испорченности" that can be used in this case:

Какой большой шарик!
Кхм...что ты имеешь в виду?
Ну, каждый понимает в меру своей испорченности!

Comment: "Гусары, молчать!" -- отличный аналог. Но не перевод, конечно.

Comment: @biggvsdiccvs Мне кажется ваш коммент - один из лучших ответов на вопрос. Если вы его запостите как ответ я за него проголосую.

Comment: Спасибо! Ответ (другой) я тоже запостил.

Comment: @biggvsdiccvs не перевод — в основном потому, что это не диалоговое выражение, а нечто, что обычно в скобках приводит сам говорящий.

Answer (score 8):

If “that's what she said” close to ["If you know what I mean"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=If+you+know+what+I+mean), тогда по-русски можно перевести почти дословно:

"Если вы понимаете, о чём я..." — если вы заканчиваете свою фразу
"Если вы понимаете, о чём он(она, они)..." — если вы заканчиваете чужую фразу

Examples from topicstarter link at Urban Dictionary:

"Make sure it's long enough. That's what she said!"
— Убедись, что он достаточно длинный. — Если вы понимаете, о чём я...

"It hurts a little but it's not too bad. THAT'S WHAT SHE SAID!!"
— Немного больно, но не так, что б уж очень. — Если вы понимаете, о чём она...

(At a hotel, describing the room key)
Clerk "Put it in, then take it out fast."
Man "That's what she said!"
— Вставить и сразу вынуть. 
— Если вы понимаете, о чём он...

[image: If you know what i mean]

Comment: Наверное единственный аналог, который может быть адекватно воспринят благодаря известности мема. "Гусары, молчать!", "... сказала она", "слова моей подружки", "теперь это так называется" - все не так очевидно, с такими аналогами шутка (и так не лучшая) точно не получится.

Answer (score 4):

Literally "сказала она". But this kind of joke not so popular in Russia.
For clarity you can use ellipsis "... сказала она".

Example from UD:

> "Make sure it's long enough."
>   "That's what she said!"

"Убедись, что он достаточно длинный."
"... сказала она!"

Answer (score 2):

Мои знакомые из забугорья,носители языка, как-то пошутили так. Закончили мою фразу и захихикали. Я не поняла, в чем прикол и попросила объяснить. Они сказали,что соль в том,что девушки как бы меньше пошлят и меньше думают о сексе,чем мужчины,поэтому когда произносится двусмысленная фраза, говорят именно "that's what SHE said". А еще из сериала "Scrubs" ( Клиника) я поняла,что в англоговорящих странах это уже бородатая и несмешная шутейка.

И по-моему, лучший перевод-это "Если вы понимаете,о чем я" с пошленькой интонацией. Ну или на крайняк "теперь это так называется?"

Answer (score 0):

"Слова моей подружки", конечно, очень топорно. Вообще трудно адекватно перевести эту шутку, как и вообще переводить шутки и каламбуры. Я бы, может быть, перевел -- "как тебе не стыдно!".

Почему-то вспоминается фильм "Борат", где какой-то американец в самом начале учит главного героя шутить, прибавляя в конце фразы слово "not".

Answer (score 0):

может как вариант:

> теперь это так называется

Comment: Обычно это встречный вопрос, так что в диалоге еще можно так перевести. А в примерах главгерой часто заканчивает "ключевой фразой" свои реплики - в этом случае не очень подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю еще один вариант не буквального перевода, но в каком-то смысле похожий: "Заметьте, не я это сказал" или же "Заметьте, не я это предложил". Правда в этом случае акцент смещен с девушки на отвечающего мужчину но суть похожа.

Comment: В урбандикшенари есть такой пример "Ого, какое длинное копьё" "Заметьте, не я это предложил" - не сильно подходит, правда? Или "Немного больно, но неплохо" - "Не я это предложил". "Убедись, что он достатосно длинный" - "Не я это предложил".

Comment: "Ого, какое длинное копьё" "Заметьте, не я это сказал" - и т.д. Я не зря предложил 2 варианта. В каких-то случаях может подойти второй.

Answer (score 0):

В русском употребляют похожие фразы "Ты сама это сказала" или "Заметь, не я это сказал".

> Mailman: "Where do you want the mail?"
> Victim: "Stick it in there."
> Mailman: "Thats what she said!"

Почтальон: "Куда вам почту?"
Жертва: "Засунь туда."
Почтальон: "Ты сама это сказала!"

Answer (score -1):

No for the analogue in Russian. There is no a direct Russian analogue, but the translation is pretty direct:

> `"That's what she said!"` - `"Она это сказала"` can be used with the meaning `"Не я это сказал"` or even `"Так говорят"`

Can be also used to make an accent on a person who said it:

> "`Она` **`сама`** `так сказала`"

Or to show doubts, as in the example below:

> John is on the phone with his Director of Human Resources (DHR).
>
> DHR: "John, your manager Mike said you do your work very slowly."
>
> John: `"That's what he said."`
>
> can express here a doubt `"Это` **`только он`** `так говорит!"` with the meaning as `"It's doubtful"`

Comment: Downvoter could comment.

Answer (score -1):

> — Так, нам надо убедиться, что мы защищены.
>   — Так она и сказала!

Не могу передать интонацию. Посмотрите [вот это видео](http://youtu.be/Qx_aco31gW4?t=1m20s) на 1:20.